# Using D3.js, can I focus a data point in a SVG chart using keyboard?

Tags: javascript, frontend, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an SVG chart creatd using D3.js in which there are data points that show up when being hovered by mouse.

Now I need to make it support motor impared people who can only use keyboard, not mouse, to interact with the chart.

I tried to use `tab` button to navigate through the chart, but the data points are not focusable and therfore don't display.

Could anyone teach me how to make it more accessible?

If D3.js doesn't support it, could you recommend another library?

BTW, is https://d3plus.org/ a better choice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, the data points each need `tabindex='0'` and some kind of accessible name, typically this would be `aria-label="string representing the datapoint"`.

I haven't touched d3 for years, but IIRC I think this should be possible. d3plus looks pretty good, and adds an `aria-label` and a `presentation role` but not a tab index to data points.

Presentation role would normally not be something you focus with the tab key. I wonder how screen readers would handle that. I can't help thinking that another [role from graphics-aria](https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0/#role_definitions) might be more suitable than `presentation`.

(Strictly speaking, the tab key is for focusing operable content, and datapoints are generally not operable, although an idiom of browsing data by tabbing is establishing itself - mostly because no other mechanism other than a data table yet exists).